# 'In x=1' vs 'At x=1'

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions, mathematics, at-in

Which sentence is correct (or maybe both are)?

1. At x=1 a maximum is observed.
2. In x=1 a maximum is observed.

Is there any rule concerning usage of 'in/at' in such situations?

Comment: Why not find a book you admire, and follow the usage from that book?  You could try others, too  ... "When x=1" ... "Near x=1" ... "On x=1" ...

Comment: @GEdgar "Near x=1" is not interchangeable with "at x=1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a question about mathematical norms, but the better answer between those two options is *At x=1*.

Compare it to these non-mathematical sentences:

> I'm getting tired of driving, do you mind switching *at the rest stop*?

or

> *At the grocery store*, don't forget to pick up some milk.

Think of a point traveling along the X axis on a graph, when it *gets* to X=1, you observe a min or max.